# Dropdown on React reopen the menu again when clicking on the outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the dropdown on the Child component and everything works perfectly until I implemented the outside click to close the dropdown.

Even on that outside clicking to close working perfectly but clicking on the menu to close it's not working as expected.

```
<div>
 <button onClick={handleAboutMenuActive}>About</button>
 {aboutMenuActive && (
   <Dropdown
      onClickOutside={() => {
         handleAboutMenuActive();
      }}
   >
   </Dropdown>
 )}
</div>
```

Here is the link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubugsj?file=src%2FApp.js

The solution I can think of now is adding setTimeout on the outside click callback but anything under 150 is not reliable so I need a different and working solution for this problem.

```
onClickOutside={() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    handleAboutMenuActive();
  }, 150);
}}
```

Here is the link to the working solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpqux7?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FDropdown.js

My question will be is that my approach to solving this problem is correct and final or do you recommend any better solution than using `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in first demo is the `handleClickOutside` triggers no matter where you clicked. When you click on the `About` button, it makes `handleAboutMenuActive` function trigger twice.

In my opinion the better way to implement this effect is to check where the user clicked. We can use [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

First, add a `ref` for the button in `App.js` and pass it as a prop to it's child component `Dropdown`:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
// some other code
export default function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef();
  // some other code
  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={handleAboutMenuActive}>About</button>
      {aboutMenuActive && (
        <Dropdown
          buttonRef={buttonRef}
          onClickOutside={() => {
            handleAboutMenuActive();
          }}
        ></Dropdown>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Second, add another `ref` for the whole `ul` element and check both ref whenever the `handleClickOutside` is triggered.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
export default function Dropdown({ buttonRef, onClickOutside }) {
  const listRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      // refs will exist after the elements are rendered.
      // this condition prevents the refs were still undefined.
      if (!listRef.current || !buttonRef.current) {
        return;
      }
      // check if user clicked on the button
      if (buttonRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      // check if user clicked on the list
      if (listRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      onClickOutside();
    }
    // some other code
  })

  return (
    <ul ref={listRef}>
      <li>Company</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```